# Java time manipulation - subtracting 2 strings

Tags: java, xml, string, swing, jodatime

I am pulling 2 time values (as strings) from an XML file using xpath, these values (for example) are as follows:

00:07

08:00

00:07 is equal to 7 minutes

08:00 means 8am, with no date associated or needed (that is handled elsewhere)

Each of these values is subject to change in each XML file that i read. What i am attempting to do is as follows:

1. I need to subtract or add (depending on the situation) the 7mins from the 8am and give me a hh:mm time (eg: 07:53 or 08:07) in a string that i can eventually output to CSV
2. Next i need to produce 2 additional strings, 1 min before and 1 min after (eg: 07:52 and 07:54 OR 08:06 and 08:08) which also need to be output to CSV

I have tried everything and i can think of in relation to the time interpretation and manipulation to get the minutes subtracted/added to the time and then +/- 1 min from there, but being a complete novice i am totally stuck despite reading and testing as much as i could find. Spent the last 2 days working with Joda Time for the first time but i must be missing something fundamental as i cannot get the desired result with this either.

The question is - how can i achieve this?

Some sample code that gets me reading from the XML and printing the time

```
 FileInputStream file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileInputStream(new File("Output/XmlConfig.xml"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(KATT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(KATT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        Document xmlDocument = null;
    try {
        xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);
    } catch (SAXException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(KATT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(KATT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        //get In Early rule from XML
        String exceptionInEarlyXML = "Root/Response/WSAExceptionRule/@InEarly";
        NodeList nodeListInEarly = null;
    try {
        nodeListInEarly = (NodeList) xPath.compile(exceptionInEarlyXML).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(KATT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        String exceptionInEarly = (nodeListInEarly.item(1).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
       String InEarly = exceptionInEarly;
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
       Date d2 = null;

    try {
        d2 = format.parse(InEarly);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(KATT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(d2);

        System.out.println(dt2);
```

This give me an output of 1970-01-01T00:07:00.000+10:00

I have tried so many permutations of code that i am at the point of deleting and starting again from scratch as it is un-compilable, and i am not experienced enough yet to be able to solve this issue.

Comment: If you have `"tried everything"` and `"spent the last 2 days..."` then please show us the fruits of your efforts.

Comment: What's wrong with 1970-01-01T00:07:00.000+10:00 ?

Comment: I do not know how to subtract x minutes from this value (00:07 based on the other string i have extracted from xml) and give me an output of 07:53.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the Date object for the parsed time, use getTime() to get the time in milliseconds and save it into a long variables.   Then parse the offset time format and use a NumberFormat to get the number of minutes to offset.  Add or subtract as needed.  Take the result and create a new Date(millis) then apply your format to it.

Here is a working example:

```
    String sTime = "08:00";
    String sOffset ="00:07";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    Date dtTime = null;
    try {
        dtTime = dateFormat.parse(sTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // handle exception
        return;
    }

    String[] offsetHrsMins = null;
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    long offsetMillis = 0;
    try {
        offsetHrsMins = sOffset.split(":");
        long offsetHrs = (Long) numberFormat.parse(offsetHrsMins[0]);
        long offsetMins = (Long) numberFormat.parse(offsetHrsMins[1]);
        offsetMillis = 1000 * 60 * ((offsetHrs * 60) + offsetMins);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // handle exception
        return;
    }

    long lTime = dtTime.getTime();

    System.out.println("Adding minutes: " + dateFormat.format(new Date(lTime + offsetMillis)));
    System.out.println("Subtracting minutes: " + dateFormat.format(new Date(lTime - offsetMillis)));
```

output:

```
Adding minutes: 08:07
Subtracting minutes: 07:53
```

Comment: Thank you - this solution seems to work well for my requirements! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the strings into a method aswel as what you are subrtacting by

Then converting them to ints

Then have an if statment that if the subtraction amount is greater that the minets int
then it subtracts 1 from the hours int and sets the new minets int to 60 subtract the subtraction int

Then convert them back to Strings
Here is the code exept for turing it back into a string

```
    public class Main {
    static String hours="8";
static String minets="7";
static String minus="17";
public static void main(String[] args) {
Main m = new Main();

m.timechange(hours,minets,minus);
}
void timechange(String hour, String minuet, String subtract){
    int h = Integer.parseInt(hour);
    int m = Integer.parseInt(minuet);
    int s = Integer.parseInt(subtract);
      if(s>m){
    h-=1;
    m=60-s;
      }
      else{
    m-=s;
      }
      if ((m>9)&&(h>9)) {
            System.out.println(h+":"+m);
        } else {if ((m<10)&&(h<10)) {
            System.out.println("0"+h+":0"+m);
        }else {if ((m<10)&&(h>9)) {
            System.out.println(h+":0"+m);
        }else {if ((m>9)&&(h<10)) {
            System.out.println("0"+h+":"+m);
        }

        }

        }
      }
}}
```

I wasnt sure if you wanted the back to String.
Hopeful that answers your question
The same can be done for when the minets reach over 60 if that ever happens.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use SimpleDateFormat to parse the Date String to a Java.util.Date Object.

Second, After getting the Date Object, you can easily add/substract some time, and get another Date Object.

Last, you can use another SimpleDateFormat object to format the Date Object you got in second step to String.

SimpleDateFormat is very useful in Processing Date Strings. You can refer to the Javadoc in JDK or search some examples by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Here a genuine Joda-Time answer because OP wants Joda-Time (and I also consider that library as superior to `java.util.Date`, `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` etc.):

Joda-Time has the big advantage of having several different temporal types. The right type for handling plain wall times is [LocalTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html). It also defines a method to add minutes.

**Your task:**

1. I need to subtract or add (depending on the situation) the 7mins from the 8am and give me a hh:mm time (eg: 07:53 or 08:07) in a string that i can eventually output to CSV
2. Next i need to produce 2 additional strings, 1 min before and 1 min after (eg: 07:52 and 07:54 OR 08:06 and 08:08) which also need to be output to CSV

**The solution (only for part one, the other part is very similar):**

```
LocalTime time = new LocalTime(8, 0); // corresponds to 08:00
LocalTime laterBy8Minutes = time.plusMinutes(7);
LocalTime earlierBy8Minutes = time.minusMinutes(7);
String sLaterBy8Minutes = laterBy8Minutes.toString("HH:mm"); // 08:07
String sEarlierBy8Minutes = earlierBy8Minutes.toString("HH:mm"); // 07:53
```

One additional note: If you start with another type like `java.util.Date` and wish to convert it to `LocalTime` then you can use the constructor

```
new LocalTime(jdkDate, DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Moscow"))  // example
```

or for default timezone:

```
new LocalTime(jdkDate)
```